# ESX Server not seeing ISCSI Device for connection to HP Lefthand SAN Array

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network, iscsi, lefthand

I have an ESX server array that I had connected to four HP SAN boxes. Unfortunately, HP only sent me three certificates (and I lost track) so it was running with only 3 of the 4 boxes cert'ed. I have called up HP, we found the cert and now all 4 are properly certified. However, vSphere no longer shows the connection to the san array or even the iscsi storage adapter at all!

I have very important data on this san and I cannot wipe it and start fresh...but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can I clarify here; the certs were for fully enabling the HP SAN arrays right? and when you added the cert to the previously-working fourth SAN array it stopped being visible? or did all SAN arrays disappear?

If just the fourth SAN box is no longer visible then I'd suggest you reboot it, connect in via the management interface and check that the array is still setup as it previously was (IP's haven't changed, disk groups still exist, hosts still defined, LUNS/VDISK still exist and are presented). If everything is still there then try connecting to the LUN/VDISK from a non-ESX based machine such as a laptop to see if the problem is the array or not.

Ultimately ensure you have HP's support number very close to hand as they may be able to help more quickly than we can and I wouldn't want you sat waiting for us ok.

Comment: Correct at the Certs. When that situation was fixed, the entire array stopped working--more correctly: the iSCSI interface on my ESX box stopped connecting to the SAN array. If no one here has experienced something similar I will reach out to HP and see what they have to say.

Thanks chopper.